# Considering $f(x) = \int_0^ \frac{\pi}{2} (\cos t)^x dt$, prove $(x+1)f(x) = (x+2)f(x+2)$

Tags: integration

Can anyone give me an idea to solve this?

Consider  $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  (\cos(t))^x dt.$$

Prove that $(x+1)f(x) = (x+2)f(x+2)$

I tried to manipulate both sides of the equation, but I couldn't get to the solution.

Any hint would help a lot!

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $$f(x)=1/2\,{\frac {\Gamma \left( x/2+1/2 \right) \sqrt {\pi}}{\Gamma \left( 
x/2+1 \right) }}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Use integrating by parts, let $u=\cos^{x+1}(t)$ and $dv=\cos(t)dt$, then
\begin{align}
f(x+2) 
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{x+2}(t)\ dt \\
&= \cos^{x+1}(t)\sin(t)\Big|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + (x+1)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{x}(t)\sin^2(t)\ dt \\
&= (x+1)f(x)-(x+1)f(x+2)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you !! <3

Comment: you are welcome.